# Comparing Distance within an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a question in comparing values within an Array and drawing a line to the points that have the largest distance.

```
   Point2D[] pts = new Point2D[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < pts.length; i++){
            pts[i] = new Point2D(Math.random(), Math.random());
            StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.RED);
            StdDraw.setPenRadius(0.008);
            pts[i].draw();
            if(SOMETHING){
                StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
                StdDraw.setPenRadius(0.002);
                pts[i].drawTo(SOMETHING);
```

so far that's part of my code that generates the random points, but I have no clue how to approach measuring the distance and then drawing it. 
Would I have to create a nested loop?
Any advice would be great!

Comment: Do you create all points first or do you want to draw a line for each created point (between the two points that are farthest from each other)?

Comment: the points are generated first and then you find the longest distance

Comment: Then you have to use a for loop to create all points first and use a nested for loop afterwards. Store the longest distance and the two points while iterating over the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that, if you only want to draw the longest *edge* (a graph theory term), **your draw call will not be inside of your for loop**.  Rather, your loop (and possibly with a second nested loop) will run through all of your possibilities and find the longest edge first, by saving and overwriting data on whichever is the most-longest it has found thus far every time it breaks the previous record, and then commence drawing once after the loop.

Comment: thank you! that enlightened to try something drastic!